# Variables not updating with Entry

Tags: python, api, tkinter, binance, cryptocurrency

Once again I am here asking for guidance with my crypto trading bot. This time, I am trying to update variables using Tkinter Entries. The default value for the Entry that I am trying to update is Crypto Symbol. I am trying to get a variable `sym` from this to use with the Binance API. I need to do `sym = crypto.get()+'USDT'` to get the variable that I need to plug into the command for the Trade button. For testing purposes, I set the command to `print(sym)` because I am trying to get it to update and that makes it easy to see what is going on. When I press the button, no matter what I have entered in the Entry, it always spits out `Crypto SymboUSDT` because `Crypto Symbol` is the original value, showing that what I am entering doesn't change anything. I will attach my code below, if you have a potential fix, please let me know :)

````
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core import frame, indexing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import Entry, Tk, filedialog, Text

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x250')
root.title('Binance Bot')



# API Key Information
api_key = 'Censored'
api__secret = 'Censored'

# Entries

#Crypto Symbol
crypto = Entry(root, width=20, borderwidth=2, fg='gray')
crypto.insert(0, "Crypto Symbol")

def cryptoFocusIn(event):
    crypto.config(foreground='black')
    if crypto.get() == 'Crypto Symbol':
        crypto.config(foreground='black')
        crypto.delete(0, END)

def cryptoFocusOut(event):
    if crypto.get() == '':
        crypto.delete(0, END)
        crypto.config(foreground='gray')
        crypto.insert(0, 'Crypto Symbol')

crypto.bind('<FocusIn>', cryptoFocusIn)
crypto.bind('<FocusOut>', cryptoFocusOut)
crypto.pack()

sym = crypto.get()+'USDT'

# Order amount
OrderAmt = Entry(root, width=20, borderwidth=2, fg='gray')
OrderAmt.insert(0, "Order Amount (Coins)")

def AmtFocusIn(event):
    OrderAmt.config(foreground='black')
    if OrderAmt.get() == 'Order Amount (Coins)':
        OrderAmt.config(foreground='black')
        OrderAmt.delete(0, END)

def AmtFocusOut(event):
    if OrderAmt.get() == '':
        OrderAmt.delete(0, END)
        OrderAmt.config(foreground='gray')
        OrderAmt.insert(0, 'Order Amount (Coins)')

OrderAmt.bind('<FocusIn>', AmtFocusIn)
OrderAmt.bind('<FocusOut>', AmtFocusOut)
OrderAmt.pack()

qty = OrderAmt.get()

#Percentage drop for bot to buy
PercentDrop = Entry(root, width=20, borderwidth=2, fg='gray')
PercentDrop.insert(0, "% Drop to Buy")

def PDFocusIn(event):
    PercentDrop.config(foreground='black')
    if PercentDrop.get() == '% Drop to Buy':
        PercentDrop.config(foreground='black')
        PercentDrop.delete(0, END)

def PDFocusOut(event):
    if PercentDrop.get() == '':
        PercentDrop.delete(0, END)
        PercentDrop.config(foreground='gray')
        PercentDrop.insert(0, '% Drop to Buy')

PercentDrop.bind('<FocusIn>', PDFocusIn)
PercentDrop.bind('<FocusOut>', PDFocusOut)
PercentDrop.pack()

#Percent gain to Sell
PercentRaise = Entry(root, width=20, borderwidth=2, fg='gray')
PercentRaise.insert(0, "% Raise to Sell")

def PRFocusIn(event):
    PercentRaise.config(foreground='black')
    if PercentRaise.get() == '% Raise to Sell':
        PercentRaise.config(foreground='black')
        PercentRaise.delete(0, END)

def PRFocusOut(event):
    if PercentRaise.get() == '':
        PercentRaise.delete(0, END)
        PercentRaise.config(foreground='gray')
        PercentRaise.insert(0, '% Raise to Sell')

PercentRaise.bind('<FocusIn>', PRFocusIn)
PercentRaise.bind('<FocusOut>', PRFocusOut)
PercentRaise.pack()

# Percent bottom out to sell - Failsafe to not lose money
PercentBottom = Entry(root, width=20, borderwidth=2, fg='gray')
PercentBottom.insert(0, "% Drop Failsafe")

def PBFocusIn(event):
    PercentBottom.config(foreground='black')
    if PercentBottom.get() == '% Drop Failsafe':
        PercentBottom.config(foreground='black')
        PercentBottom.delete(0, END)

def PBFocusOut(event):
    if PercentBottom.get() == '':
        PercentBottom.delete(0, END)
        PercentBottom.config(foreground='gray')
        PercentBottom.insert(0, '% Drop Failsafe')

PercentBottom.bind('<FocusIn>', PBFocusIn)
PercentBottom.bind('<FocusOut>', PBFocusOut)
PercentBottom.pack()

# Get account information
client = Client(api_key, api__secret, tld='us')
#print(client.get_account())

# Datastream via websocket

def getMinuteData(symbol, interval, lookback):
    frame = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, interval, lookback+' min ago EST'))
    frame = frame.iloc[:, :6]
    frame.columns = ['Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
    frame = frame.set_index('Time')
    frame.index = pd.to_datetime(frame.index, unit='ms')
    frame = frame.astype(float)
    return frame

test = getMinuteData('BTCUSDT', '1m', '30')

# Trading Strategy - Buy if asset fell by more than 0.2% withint the last 30 min
# Sell if asset rises by more than 0.15% or falls further by 0.15%

def strategyTest(symbol, qty, entered=False):
    df = getMinuteData(symbol, '1m', '30')
    cumulRet = (df.Open.pct_change() + 1).cumprod() -1
    if not entered:
        if cumulRet [-1] < -0.002:
            order = client.create_order(symbol=symbol, side='BUY', type = 'MARKET', quantity=qty)
            print(order)
            entered = True
        else:
            print("No trade executed")
    
    if entered:
        while True:
            df = getMinuteData(symbol, '1m', '30')
            sinceBuy = df.loc[df.index > pd.to_datetime(order['transactTime'], unit='ms')]
            if len(sinceBuy) > 0:
                sinceBuyReturns = (sinceBuy.Open.pct_change() + 1).cumprod() -1
                if sinceBuyReturns[-1] > 0.0015 or sinceBuyReturns[-1] < -0.0015:
                    order = client.create_order(symbol=symbol, side='SELL', type = 'MARKET', quantity=qty)
                    print(order)
                    break

def confirm():
    sym = crypto.get()+'USDT'
    qty = OrderAmt.get()

# Buttons
Confirm = tk.Button(root, text='Confirm?', padx=10, pady=5, fg = 'white', bg = 'black', command = lambda: confirm() )
Confirm.pack()
#Trade = tk.Button(root, text='Trade', padx=10, pady=10, fg='white', bg='black', command = lambda: strategyTest(sym, qty) )
Trade = tk.Button(root, text='Trade', padx=10, pady=5, fg='white', bg='black', command = lambda: print(sym) )

Trade.pack()

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: print(sym) does not print the current contents of an Entry, it prints the current value of a variable named "sym".  You initialized that variable near the beginning of your script, and didn't change it.

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve].